# How to use union const members?

Tags: d

Suppose I have this simplified class:

```
class A {
    this(const char* result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    private:
        union{
            const char** results;
            const char* result;
        }
}
```

Compilation fails with `constructor app.A.this missing initializer for const field results`. I know I can make it compile if I remove the `const` qualifier in the union definition, but I know the members are const.

---

Edit:

When I change the code to:

```
class A {
    this(const char* result)
    {
        this.U.result = result;
    }

    private:
        union U {
            const char** results;
            const char* result;
        }
}
```

I get another error: `Error: need 'this' for 'result' of type 'const(char*)'`.

BTW, I use dmd v2.068.2

Comment: Are you sure that is your usage of const is correct? What exactly is const?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest is to just initialize it:

```
    this.results = null;
    this.result = result;
```

Make sure to set the ones you aren't using first, since you don't want to overwrite the union with null!

You could also make it a named union:

```
    union A{
        const char** results;
        const char* result;
    }

    A a;

this(const char* result)
{
    this.a.result = result;
}
```

Then the compiler realizes they are all one field and only asks for initialization once.

I think it is arguably a bug that your code doesn't work... looks like the compiler treats the anonymous union and struct the same way, when then union should be different since one variable covers them all.

But the workaround of simply setting both works so that's how I'd do it now. edit: actually, I think I prefer the named union option. Then it is a bit more obvious that they are together when reading the code later.

Comment: Do you think I should file a bug? If so, against what? DMD?

Comment: You left a line out: notice in my thing there's also an `A a;` under the union. When you use a named union, like a named struct, you also need to declare a variable of that type to access it. Notice I also used a lowercase `a` when setting.

Comment: yeah if you do file a bug it would be against dmd

Comment: The patch is written: https://github.com/D-Programming-Language/dmd/pull/5242. So fast!

Answer (score 1):

I think that your code does not make sense. I guess your usage of const is wrong.

```
class A {
    this(const(char)* result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    private:
    union
    {
        const(const(char)*)* results; // maybe const(char)** results
        const(char)* result;
    }
}
```

Or you coud just remove union:

```
class A {
    this(const char* result)
    {
        this.result = result;
    }

    private:
    const char* result;        
}
```

because `const char** result` could not be change anyway.

Comment: Outer level const is allowed for members that never change outside the constructor. The difference between `const char*` and `const(char)*` is the latter can be reassigned to a different string, whereas the former cannot be reassigned at all.

Comment: Yep, I know, so it does not make sense to use union with two const variables, if you have only one constructor which setup one of them, so you would never be able to setup the other one

Comment: It sometimes makes sense to read the same thing as two types though. I'm assuming there's a lot more context in the real code we aren't seeing here.